# How to get last pattern using regexpression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, pattern-matching

```
var a = 'a.b.c.d.e.f'
a = a.split('.');
var len = a.length;
var pattern = a[len-2]+'.'+a[len-1]
console.log(pattern);
```

It is working absolutely fine but I have to do it using regexp is there a way we can achieve same result using regular expression

or Any other way that would be efficient solution for getting only last 2 string that is separated with DOT (.) character.

Comment: so you need `e.f` as result?

Comment: yes I always want last 2 string separated with dot. eg a.b result would be a.b

a.b.c result is b.c

ab.c.d.e result is d.e

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression which looks for the last characters separated by dot.

> ```
> /[^.]+\.[^.]+$/
> ```
>
> - `[^.]+` **match a single character not present in the list below**
>
>   `Quantifier:` `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed `[greedy]`
>
>   `.` the literal character `.`
> - `\.` matches the character `.` literally
> - `[^.]+` **match a single character not present in the list below**
>
>   `Quantifier:` `+` Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed `[greedy]`
>
>   `.` the literal character `.`
> - `$` assert position at end of the string

```js
console.log('a.b.c.d.e.f'.match(/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/, ''));
console.log('zz.yy.xx.ww.vv.uu'.match(/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/, ''));
console.log('number with.dot'.match(/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/, ''));
```